# Minimal pairs for i vs ɪ and is there an important difference?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

According to [a vowel question in Linguistic SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/31250/which-language-has-the-most-vowel-phonemes), English can be considered to have vowels  [i ɪ e ɛ æ ɑ ɔ o ʊ u ʌ] which can be reduced to  [i e æ ɑ o u ʌ] (plus an orthogonal length or diphthongization).

I use https://tophonetics.com/ for IPA phonetic transcription, which gives for "still steel" RP transcription /stɪl stiːl/, American /stɪl stil/, where I hear /i/ in American /stil/ as longer version of /ɪ/, as used in RP.

So is there a important difference? Are there minimal pairs? Does the difference depend on a dialect, distinct in some and non-distinct in other dialects?

In [How to measure auditory distances between vowels](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/33574/how-to-measure-auditory-distances-between-vowels), one chart does not mention /ɪ/ separately at all, the other one places it close to /i/.

I have few more related questions about /e ɛ/ ; /ʊ u/ and /ɑ ɔ/, which I plan to ask here, on ELL, or linguistics, depending how you will find my question be appropriate here :-)

I learned my English using [i e æ ɑ o u ʌ] vowel system, I am curious how wrong I am compared to full [i ɪ e ɛ æ ɑ ɔ o ʊ u ʌ].

**Edit: I am aware about short vs long vowels** (lax vs tense in proper linguistics lingo, IIUC). So my question is, if there is an important (distinguishable) difference between (short) /i/ and /ɪ/, and/or between (long) /i:/ and /ɪ:/ - if such sound as /ɪ:/ exists in English.

Also, I wanted to add "minimal-pair" tag, but none exists, not sure if it will be appropriate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question belongs on Linguistic SE

Comment: If it belongs to Linguistics, can you please transfer it there? But I asked not as a linguist (I am NOT a linguist), but as a learner of English :-)

Comment: It won't hurt people here to learn that there are several systems for transcribing English vowels. Some use colons for the tense high and mid vowels (/i/ = /i:/, /ɪ/ = /i/, etc.). The fact is that English distinguishes tense and lax vowels in the front and back high and mid positions, and the distinctions have heavy functional loads, especially with the front vowels. So, yes, the distinction is an important one, and it causes plenty of problems for English learners. Both lax and tense vowels can occur in closed syllables, but normally only tense vowels can occur finally.

Comment: Minimal pairs, _sheep/ship, beat/bit, seat/sit, read/rid, meat/mitt, scene/sin_, and many more. For /e/ ~ /ɛ/, _mate/met, bait/bet, mane/men, lace/less, male/Mel,_ and _rake/wreck._

Comment: @JohnLawler -  I thought that there is single IPA standard, was I mistaken? :-) So it seems that in RP: ʃiːp/ʃɪp, biːt/bɪt, in AE: ʃip/ʃɪp, bit/bɪt. For me, difference is in the length: /i:/ lasts longer than /ɪ/. So there is no /i/ in RP, only /i:/? That would solve it

Comment: mane/men, lace/less in IPA: meɪn/mɛn, leɪs/lɛs -- does it mean that /e/ is only in diphthongs like /eɪ/ ?

Comment: lax/tense vowels: "Lax vowels are also called short vowels, and tense vowels are also called long vowels"  -- For me short/long are easier to remember, and lax/tense is just linguistic conspiracy mumbo-jumbo :-)

Comment: But thank you for the lax vs tense distinction: google gave me lots of pages to read.

Comment: "Lax/tense" is simply descriptive; it describes the tongue muscle. "Long/short" is descriptive for Middle English, but just an arbitrary name like "Regular/Ethyl" when it comes to identifying vowels. There are those who find what they learned in grammar school intellectual comfort food, and there's nothing wrong with that. But not all "long" vowels are tense, and not all "short" vowels are lax; the terms don't match because one describes reality and the other is just a folk tale.